# I have to read a file and use Linked Lists to store the data in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to read a file and use Linked Lists to store the data.
the file look like this:

```
9 92 38 2 magenta 0
54 117 7 46 red 0
129 15 29 49 cyan 0
165 143 33 47 magenta 0
```

so my struct is this :

```
    struct rect
{ 
    int x;
    int y; 
    int w;
    int h;
    char c[7];
    int fill;
    int ID;
    int area;
    struct rect* next;
};
typedef struct rect rect_t;
rect_t *head;
```

my programm works fine and its storing the data currently, but for the last part I have to print the colors and the id of each color that exists
so my output should be something like this:

```
red: 1
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan: 2
magenta: 0 , 3
black:
```

each line of the .txt file is the ID number.

for the colors i have an enumerator:

```
enum Colors {red,green,blue,yellow,cyan,magenta,black};
```

and im using this function to get its color:

```
char* sColorNames(int iColorNumber){
    switch(iColorNumber){
        case red:
            return "red";
            break;
        case green:
            return "green";
            break;
        case blue:
            return "blue";
            break;
        case yellow:
            return "yellow";
            break;
        case cyan:
            return "cyan";
            break;
        case magenta:
            return "magenta";
            break;
        case black:
            return "black";
            break;
    }
}
```

my code for this part is something like this:

```
void PrintColorsID(int n){
    rect_t *current;
    current = head;
    int cnt2,cnt1,counter;
        for(cnt1 = red; cnt1 < black + 1; cnt1++){
            printf("%s:",sColorNames(cnt1));
            for(cnt2; cnt2 < n; cnt2++){
                if(strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            for(cnt2; cnt2 < n; cnt2++){
                if(strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0 && counter > 1){
                    printf(" %d",current->ID);
                }
                else if(strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0 && counter == 1){
                    printf(" %d",current->ID);
                    break;
                }
            }
            putchar('\n');
            }       
}
```

By doing that the result Im getting is this:

```
red: 
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan: 
magenta: 
black:
```

I also tried with a while loop:

```
void PrintColorsID(int n){
    rect_t* current;
    current = head;
    int cnt1,cnt2,counter;
    while(current!=NULL){
            for(cnt1 = red; cnt1 < black + 1; cnt1++){
                printf("%s:",sColorNames(cnt1));
                for(cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < n; cnt2++){
                    if(strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0){
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                if(strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0 && counter > 1){
                    printf(" %d",current->ID);
                    counter--;  
                }
                else if (strcmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1)) == 0 && counter == 1){
                    printf(" %d",current->ID);
                    break;
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            current = current->next;
    }
}
```

but the output i get is this:

```
red:
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan:
magenta: 0
black:
red: 1
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan:
magenta:
black:
red:
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan: 2
magenta:
black:
red:
green:
blue:
yellow:
cyan:
magenta: 3
black:
```

Can anyboy tell me with this is happening? i cant think of a different way of doing that.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your code you are trying to loop through the existing enum list of colors, and checking whther it has an entry in list, and printing name and ID.

I believe, you need not have to have "counter" implemetation and "cnt2" loop.

code which u have shared with while (first code doesnt seems to be correct or a compiled version).

also in your code you have not placed enoguh space for endof string char. so there is chnace that strcmp functions may fail.

```
    void PrintColorsID(int n){
        rect_t* current;
        current = head;
        int cnt1 = 0;
        int isfirst = 1;
        for(cnt1 = red; cnt1 < black; cnt1++){
            printf("%s:",sColorNames(cnt1));
            current = head;
            isfirst = 1;
            while(current!=NULL){                         
                    if(strncmp(current->c,sColorNames(cnt1),7) == 0){
                        if (isfirst) {
                             isfirst = 0;
                        } else {
                              printf(",");
                        }
                        printf(" %d",current->ID);                           
                    }
                    
                    current = current->next;
             }     
             printf("\n");           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked and it was really helpful ,but in that way how can I print the " , " only if there are more IDs with the same color?

Comment: keep a flag outside while, isfirst = 1, inside strncmp if segment if (!isfirst) { printf(",");} , also set isfirst =0;